# Can I GET without the ID?

Tags: rest, postman

I need to get a result from a table where I only know a few values from a report.
Which is the EntryID found on the 3rd line and the description
I'm only new to RestApi's
But how could i filter through and fine this particular result without having the transaction ID.

My url looks something like this

> `https://publicfacingURL/ServerName/services/select/Transaction/{transactionid}`

```
         <Transaction>
            <TransactionID>1656286</TransactionID>
            <EntryID>39013</EntryID>
            <ChargeGroupID>88</ChargeGroupID>
            <ChargeItemID>0</ChargeItemID>
            <TransactionTypeEnum>Payment</TransactionTypeEnum>
            <TransactionDate>2020-01-04T22:22:57.427</TransactionDate>
            <ProcessedDate>2020-01-04T22:23:44.74</ProcessedDate>
            <DueDate />
            <Description>Web account payment #WEBR123123</Description>
            <Amount>-398.0000</Amount>             
            <Duration>0</Duration>
            <CallTypeEnum>Other</CallTypeEnum>
            <Comments>CC Type used: Visa</Comments>
            <Reference_BookingID>0</Reference_BookingID>
            <PaidFrom />
            <PaidTo />
            <Excess>0</Excess>
            <ExternalReceiptID></ExternalReceiptID>
            <DateModified>2020-01-04T22:23:44.773</DateModified>
        </Transaction>
```

Comment: I believe you can't do that. Unless you configure the API to return everything when there is no id provided.

Comment: Is the backend written by you? The answer to the question depends on the backend implementation. Maybe you can also write a endpoint which takes entryId as input.

Comment: Hi Deepak, Its written by another team in the dep, they just dont have the time to implement. I can get to entryID but that result does not show any <transaction> children when i use the below endpoint
https://publicfacingURL/ServerName/services/select/Entry/{entryid}

Answer (score 0):

I just updated to reflect the following below.

https://publicfacingurl/ServerName/services/select/transaction?entryid={entryId}

Thanks for everyone's help.